# Flutter degugging APK

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

Sorry for my bad English. I'm trying to build an APK 2-nd day and haven't results. Every time after fixing some error I'm getting a new problem.

Now I'm trying to launch my application on Android device and getting an errors:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Smartphone in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2e94107f30f39be366a17347c2bf100b\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.

     C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2e94107f30f39be366a17347c2bf100b\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.

     C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2e94107f30f39be366a17347c2bf100b\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.

     C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2e94107f30f39be366a17347c2bf100b\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2e94107f30f39be366a17347c2bf100b\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

     C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2e94107f30f39be366a17347c2bf100b\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:174:5-210:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/startX not found.

     C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2e94107f30f39be366a17347c2bf100b\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:174:5-210:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/startY not found.

     C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2e94107f30f39be366a17347c2bf100b\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:174:5-210:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/endX not found.

     C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2e94107f30f39be366a17347c2bf100b\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:174:5-210:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/endY not found.

     C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2e94107f30f39be366a17347c2bf100b\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:211:5-217:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/offset not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

What's problem? Thanks.

Comment: what was your flutter doctor result?